# How to prompt a user using scan.nextInt for int type in a while loop?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

```
System.out.println("How long is the word you would like to guess?");
    while (goodInput==false)
            {
                try
                {
                    wordSize=scan.nextInt();
                    goodInput=true;
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ime)
                {
                    System.out.println("Thats not a number! Try again");
                }
            }
```

The console repeats the "Thats not a number..." in infinite loop after the wrong type of input is entered.

*edit

I tried

```
while(goodInput==false)
        {
            if (scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                wordSize=scan.nextInt();
                goodInput=true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Thats not a number! Try again");
            }
        }
```

which also produces same error

Comment: You should probably use the `scan.hasNextInt()` method instead of catching exceptions.

Comment: what is the type of wordSize?

Comment: @Fyre assuming the code compiles, it can only be `int` or `Integer`

Comment: You probably need to read the next line character using .nextline method after .nextint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never consume the input if a non-integer is supplied, so the input is passed through again and again resulting in an infinite loop. You *could* use:

```
scan.nextLine();
```

in your exception block but better to use:

```
while (scan.hasNextInt() && !goodInput) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 while (goodInput==false) {
      System.out.println("How long is the word you would like to guess?");
      if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        wordSize=scan.nextInt();
        goodInput=true;
      }
      else scan.next();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but the question was just answered.